# How does sklearn.clusters.KMeans.lables_ work in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, python-3.7

I'm working with a piece of poorly documented code, and while trying to dodge an issue with a .pkl file that has been giving me grief, I ran into another issue with sklearn. The code is as follows:

```
km = KMeans(algorithm=None, copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
n_clusters=5, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances=True,
random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
```

And, to the best of my knowledge, it is supposed to provide a way to sort documents into clusters. However, this instead gives me:

> AttributeError: KMeans has no attribute lables_

This is very odd because in the `sklearn` documentation online, it shows an attribute called lables_. Here is the link to the website: [scikit-doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

I have no idea why this isn't working. I guess is that there is a compatibility issue with `Python 3.7` (which is what I'm using). There is also a possibility that "km" doesn't work for some reason, which would most likely be an issue with the .pkl file I got it from. Googling around, I haven't found anyone else talking about this AttributeError, so I am thinking that the issue might be with "km" rather than with "clusters", I was just hoping that someone here would know.

Comment: First you need to `fit()` the data, only after that those attributes are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `fit()` on your data before accessing the `labels_`.
See below code:

```
km = KMeans(algorithm=None, copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
n_clusters=5, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances=True,
random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)

km.fit(data)

clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
```